# How to get the callback when losing the signal of BLE?

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have some problem about BLE scan on Android.
I want to get the details of disconnecting device.
I can get the information by using `startScan(filters,settings,leScanCallback);`
Here is my code:

```
BluetoothManager btManager =(BluetoothManager)getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);
BluetoothAdapter btAdapter=btManager.getAdapter();
BluetoothLeScanner btScanner=btAdapter.getBluetoothLeScanner();
ScanFilter filter = new ScanFilter.Builder().setDeviceAddress("E0:E5:CF:32:95:B2").build();
                List<ScanFilter> filters = new ArrayList<>();
                filters.add(filter);
                ScanSettings settings = new ScanSettings.Builder()
                        .setScanMode(ScanSettings.SCAN_MODE_BALANCED)
                        .setCallbackType(ScanSettings.CALLBACK_TYPE_ALL_MATCHES)
                        .build();
                btScanner.startScan(filters,settings,leScanCallback);

    private ScanCallback leScanCallback = new ScanCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onScanResult(int callbackType, ScanResult result) {

                super.onScanResult(callbackType,result);

                Log.d(ACTIVITY_TAG, String.format("message:%d %s", callbackType,result.getDevice().getAddress()));
            }
   }
```

Work but the lost message is not received. I tried to use `ScanSettings.CALLBACK_TYPE_FIRST_MATCH|ScanSettings.CALLBACK_TYPE_MATCH_LOST`.However it doesn't show any message.How can I trigger the function when connecting for the first time or disconnecting device?

Answer (score 0):

Just add this broadcast receiver in your code, you can get notify by this receiver, just register receiver once you connect your BLE device.

```
private final BroadcastReceiver mBroadcastReceiverBluetoothEnableStatus = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String action = intent.getAction();
            // When discovery finds a device
            if (action.equals(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED)) {
                final int state = intent.getIntExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_STATE, BluetoothAdapter.ERROR);

                switch (state) {
                    case BluetoothAdapter.STATE_OFF:
                        Log.d(TAG, "onReceive: STATE OFF");
                        break;
                    case BluetoothAdapter.STATE_TURNING_OFF:
                        Log.d(TAG, "mBroadcastReceiverBluetoothEnableStatus: STATE TURNING OFF");
                        break;
                    case BluetoothAdapter.STATE_ON:
                        Log.d(TAG, "mBroadcastReceiverBluetoothEnableStatus: STATE ON");
                        scanDevice();
                        break;
                    case BluetoothAdapter.STATE_TURNING_ON:
                        Log.d(TAG, "mBroadcastReceiverBluetoothEnableStatus: STATE TURNING ON");
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    };
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Your code shows a BroadcastReceiver, receiving changes when the local Bluetooth adapter is turned on/off.

Comment: It is useful to detect Bluetooth state, but it's unhelpful to solve my question. I should know whether I leave the BLE device.

Answer (score 0):

I've tested this hack works for API 24 and up. It does not seem to work on API 23 and below.

If you start two different scans, with two different ScanCallbacks (this is critical!), then you'll get results for both scans. Example:

```
  ScanCallback scanCallback = createScanCallback();
  ScanFilter filter = createScanFilter();
  ScanSettings settings =
      new ScanSettings.Builder().setScanMode(ScanSettings.SCAN_MODE_LOW_LATENCY).build();
  scanner.startScan(Lists.newArrayList(filter), settings, scanCallback);

  ScanSettings deviceLostSettings =
        new ScanSettings.Builder()
            .setCallbackType(ScanSettings.CALLBACK_TYPE_MATCH_LOST)
            .build();
  // This ScanCallback object MUST be different than the first. 
  ScanCallback deviceLostCallback = createDeviceLostCallback(); 
  scanner.startScan(Lists.newArrayList(filter), deviceLostSettings, deviceLostCallback);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `callbackType` parameter of the `ScanCallback`. You can check it in the `onScanResult` function

Like so:

```
when (callbackType) {
    ScanSettings.CALLBACK_TYPE_FIRST_MATCH -> _btDevices.add(result.device)
    ScanSettings.CALLBACK_TYPE_MATCH_LOST -> _btDevices.remove(result.device)
}
```